Temporarily delete keywords from lstlistings
As a follow-up of the previous question lstlistings more keywords I would like to delete some keywords for a particular snippet of code
\documentclass{article}

% Use utf8 input encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Use Latin Modern high-quality fonts
\usepackage{lmodern}

% For colors
\usepackage{xcolor}

% To have the \textquotesingle in listings
\usepackage{textcomp}
% For listings
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{columns=fullflexible, showstringspaces=false,
  extendedchars=true,% Enable UTF8 accentuated characters
  upquote=true,% Straight quotes in code
  basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},% We cannot use '*' to make keywords appear in upper case
  commentstyle=\color{purple},%
}
\lstdefinelanguage{mySQL}{%
  language=SQL,
  alsoletter={&},
  % literate={-}{-}1, % Do not replace hyphen by minus symbol
  % alsodigit={-},
  % alsoletter={-},
  morecomment=[l][commentstyle]{--},%
  morecomment=[s][commentstyle]{/*}{*/},%
  morekeywords={ALWAYS,BIGINT,BOOLEAN,COPY,COSTS,EPOCH,EXPLAIN,
    FILTER,FOR,FUNCTION,GENERATED,GROUPING,HASH,IF,IS,LATERAL,
    LEAD,LIST,MODE,MODULUS,OF,OFF,ON,OVER,PARALLEL,PARTITION,
    PRECEDING,RANGE,RANK,REFERENCES,REMAINDER,SETS,SYSTEM,
    TABLESAMPLE,TEXT,TIMESTAMPTZ,TO,UNBOUNDED,UNSAFE,WITH,
    WITHIN,WITHOUT}}
% To disable the replacement of hyphen with minus sign
\makeatletter
\lst@CCPutMacro
  \lst@ProcessOther {"2A}{\lst@ttfamily{*{}}{*}}
  \lst@ProcessOther {"2D}{\lst@ttfamily{-{}}{-}}
  \@empty\z@\@empty
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is a test for color highlighting using the lstlistings package. 
I would like to remove two keywords just in the example below.

\begin{lstlisting}[language=mySQL,deletekeywords={lower,upper}]
CREATE TABLE AdaptiveGrid(TileId, RowNo, ColNo, Tile, Geom) AS
WITH TableSRID(SRID) AS (
  SELECT ST_SRID(Point) FROM AllPoints LIMIT 1 ),
Tiles(TileId, RowNo, ColNo, Tile) AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(), YBinId, XBinId,
    stboxX(lower(XSpan), lower(YSpan), upper(XSpan), upper(YSpan), SRID)
  FROM YBins y, XBins x, TableSRID s
  ORDER BY YBinId, XBinId )
SELECT TileId, RowNo, ColNo, Tile, Tile::geometry
FROM Tiles;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}

Alas the keywords are still color highlighted.


I am sorry for this. Now the code is compilable.

You can put the keywords that should only be in effect in parts of your document into another keyword group and switch the style of these, so for instance use morekeywords=[2]{ALWAYS},keywordstyle=[2]\color{blue} and then for the part where you don't want ALWAYS to be blue use keywordstyle=[2]{}.

You seem to have duplicate accounts. Do you want them merged?

The listings language definition of SQL defines LOWER and UPPER in all-caps:
%%
%% SQL definition (c) 1998 Christian Haul
%%                (c) 2002 Neil Conway
%%                (c) 2002 Robert Frank
%%                (c) 2003 Dirk Jesko
%%
\lst@definelanguage{SQL}%
  {morekeywords={ABSOLUTE,ACTION,ADD,ALLOCATE,ALTER,ARE,AS,ASSERTION,%
      AT,BEGIN,BETWEEN,BIT_LENGTH,BOTH,BY,CASCADE,CASCADED,CASE,CAST,%
      CATALOG,CHAR_LENGTH,CHARACTER_LENGTH,CLUSTER,COALESCE,%
      COLLATE,COLLATION,COLUMN,CONNECT,CONNECTION,CONSTRAINT,%
      CONSTRAINTS,CONVERT,CORRESPONDING,CREATE,CROSS,CURRENT_DATE,%
      CURRENT_TIME,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_USER,DAY,DEALLOCATE,%
      DEC,DEFERRABLE,DEFERED,DESCRIBE,DESCRIPTOR,DIAGNOSTICS,%
      DISCONNECT,DOMAIN,DROP,ELSE,END,EXEC,EXCEPT,EXCEPTION,EXECUTE,%
      EXTERNAL,EXTRACT,FALSE,FIRST,FOREIGN,FROM,FULL,GET,GLOBAL,%
      GRAPHIC,HAVING,HOUR,IDENTITY,IMMEDIATE,INDEX,INITIALLY,INNER,%
      INPUT,INSENSITIVE,INSERT,INTO,INTERSECT,INTERVAL,%
      ISOLATION,JOIN,KEY,LAST,LEADING,LEFT,LEVEL,LIMIT,LOCAL,LOWER,%
      MATCH,MINUTE,MONTH,NAMES,NATIONAL,NATURAL,NCHAR,NEXT,NO,NOT,NULL,%
      NULLIF,OCTET_LENGTH,ON,ONLY,ORDER,ORDERED,OUTER,OUTPUT,OVERLAPS,%
      PAD,PARTIAL,POSITION,PREPARE,PRESERVE,PRIMARY,PRIOR,READ,%
      RELATIVE,RESTRICT,REVOKE,RIGHT,ROWS,SCROLL,SECOND,SELECT,SESSION,%
      SESSION_USER,SIZE,SPACE,SQLSTATE,SUBSTRING,SYSTEM_USER,%
      TABLE,TEMPORARY,THEN,TIMEZONE_HOUR,%
      TIMEZONE_MINUTE,TRAILING,TRANSACTION,TRANSLATE,TRANSLATION,TRIM,%
      TRUE,UNIQUE,UNKNOWN,UPPER,USAGE,USING,VALUE,VALUES,%
      VARGRAPHIC,VARYING,WHEN,WHERE,WRITE,YEAR,ZONE,%
      AND,ASC,avg,CHECK,COMMIT,count,DECODE,DESC,DISTINCT,GROUP,IN,% FF
      LIKE,NUMBER,ROLLBACK,SUBSTR,sum,VARCHAR2,% FF
      MIN,MAX,UNION,UPDATE,% RF
      ALL,ANY,CUBE,CUBE,DEFAULT,DELETE,EXISTS,GRANT,OR,RECURSIVE,% DJ
      ROLE,ROLLUP,SET,SOME,TRIGGER,VIEW},% DJ
   morendkeywords={BIT,BLOB,CHAR,CHARACTER,CLOB,DATE,DECIMAL,FLOAT,% DJ
      INT,INTEGER,NUMERIC,SMALLINT,TIME,TIMESTAMP,VARCHAR},% moved here
   sensitive=false,% DJ
   morecomment=[l]--,%
   morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},%
   morestring=[d]',%
   morestring=[d]"%
  }[keywords,comments,strings]

You can delete them by also using all-caps:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{columns=fullflexible, showstringspaces=false,
  basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=SQL,deletekeywords={LOWER,UPPER}]
CREATE TABLE AdaptiveGrid(TileId, RowNo, ColNo, Tile, Geom) AS
WITH TableSRID(SRID) AS (
  SELECT ST_SRID(Point) FROM AllPoints LIMIT 1 ),
Tiles(TileId, RowNo, ColNo, Tile) AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(), YBinId, XBinId,
    stboxX(lower(XSpan), lower(YSpan), upper(XSpan), upper(YSpan), SRID)
  FROM YBins y, XBins x, TableSRID s
  ORDER BY YBinId, XBinId )
SELECT TileId, RowNo, ColNo, Tile, Tile::geometry
FROM Tiles;
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}


